# removing space from output Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, space

```
elif clocked > limit and clocked <= 90:
    print "Too fast! The fine is $", (clocked - limit) * 5 + 50
else:
    print "Thats was extremely dangerous!\nYour fine is $", \
                                 (clocked - limit) * 5 + 250
```

Hi, the output for the `elif` would like: Too fast! The fine is $ 50. I obviously want to get rid of the space between $ 50. I know I can introduce a new variable to assign my expression and then format the variable created with no spacing but is there any way around to skip adding new variable to the code? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to introduce a new variable to use string formatting.

```
print "Too fast! The fine is ${0}".format((clocked - limit) * 5 + 50)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change to use string interpolation (although if you're using 2.6+ - it won't hurt to use `str.format` intead as pointed out by @bobince)

```
print "Too fast! The fine is $%d" % ((clocked - limit) * 5 + 50,)
```

Comment: Yep - neither `%` nor `.format` require a variable, any expression will do.

Comment: thanks @Jon, i was experimenting with the % format here but my code lacked the second () thus was getting an error.